How do I realize a dynamically stacked plot below another function with Plotly?
As the title says, I want to make a plot with Plotly which is very dynamic. The data for the curve can change as well as the data blocks which should be below the curve at all times. The idea is, that the stacked plot below the curve shows which element fills up the area below to what point.
Example
Im also open for other ideas how I could represent this data.
I realized what I want is some kind of stacked plot, but Im struggling to find a way to limit the stacked plot with my curve.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
